# Angularjs - function into custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to angularjs. Currently I am working on custom directives. 
In my program for multiselect, I was using typeahead in three places. But I was thinking that to convert the whole thing into a directive and make that use in my program.

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="multitext-wrap blue-border">
            <ul inputfocus>
                <li class="tag" ng-repeat="list in selectedOrgs">
                    <span class="tag-label">{{list.displayConfig[0].propertyValue}}</span><span class="tag-cross pointer" ng-click="removeOrg($index);">x</span>
                </li>
                <li class="">   
                    <input type="text" class="typeahead" ng-model="data.selectedOrg" typeahead-on-select="updateOrgs(data.selectedOrg); data.selectedOrg=''" typeahead="org as org.searchList for org in orgList | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control" ng-keyup="getOrgs(data.selectedOrg, $event)">

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Js code for the function calls:

```
$scope.updateOrgs = function(selectedVal) {
        var continueFlag = true;
        for(var i=0;i<$scope.selectedOrgs.length;i++){
          if($scope.selectedOrgs[i].id == selectedVal.id)
            continueFlag = false;
        }
          if(continueFlag) {
            var data = {
              orgId:selectedVal.id,
              baseObjectTemplateId:$routeParams.groupId
            };
            MapOrgs().save(data).$promise.then(

              function(val){
                console.log(val);
                $scope.selectedOrgs.push(selectedVal);
              },
              function(err){

              });
          }

      }


      $scope.getOrgs = function(data, event) {
        if(event.keyCode != 13){
          //$scope.Participants(data);
         $scope.organisationSearch(data);
        }
      }

      $scope.organisationSearch = function(filter){
        SearchOrg().fetch({'filter':filter, 'searchType':'tei_org'}).$promise.then(

          function(value){
            $scope.orgList = value.data;

          },
          function(err){

          });
//           console.log('orglist'+JSON.stringify($scope.orgList));
      }

      }],
      templateUrl : TAPPLENT_CONFIG.HTML_ENDPOINT[0]+'home/question-partials/orgs.html'

    };
  }])
```

I was trying to convert it to directive but they were not working properly, I don't know why. So please help to get rid from this problem.

Comment: so where is your code for making directive?